# Jquery and Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

So I'm trying to collapse a sidebar which I have stored as an angular element. I've tried using the toggle script in the template URL and in my page code but neither are doing it. On every other page of the site, I still have the sidebar in non-angular form and it is collapsing without a problem.

[heres the problem](http://mhsscioly.com/anatomy.html)

[plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/U9p3kqunqioYOy8ywAcG?p=catalogue)

```
<div ng-app="appHeaderApp">
<div ng-controller="sidebarcon">
  <div ng-repeat="stab in mySideTabs">
    <app-sidebar info="stab"></app-sidebar>
  </div>
  <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: that isnt the right way to use angular.

Comment: Are you using Angular to collapse a sidebar?

Comment: So I use angular to store the sidebar, that way it'll change throughout my site if I make a change to the links or layout there. what I need to do is somehow collapse it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer for this is that you are not using Angular correctly. If you're using Angular, do things the Angular way :)

After inspecting your website, it looks like you are using a directive for the sidebar. The collapsing functionality is being controlled by the "toggled" class, so we can use ng-class to toggle this.

So we can do something like:
`<div ng-class="{toggled: toggled}"></div>`

This conditionally applies a class. Then in your button that toggles the sidebar, you can do something like:
`<button ng-click="toggled = !toggled">Toggle Sidebar</button>`

This button will toggled the "toggled" boolean back and forth, which will toggle the class on the sidebar.

Comment: so do i scrap the #menu-toggle entirely?

Comment: You mean the jQuery click handler? Yeah, you don't need that. Let Angular handle click events for you

Comment: okay, I'll trash that then. How would I go about toggling? Doesn't the jquery define that boolean for changing states?

Comment: No, that boolean should be defined in your Angular controller as `$scope.toggled = false;` (assuming it starts closed. If you want it to start open, you would set it to true).

Comment: that would be in my app module correct? Where would i define these terms or are they native. Sorry I'm new to angular

Comment: Yes, you'd need to create a new controller for your sidebar in your module. I highly recommend taking some Angular tutorials, as you'll need these fundamentals to move forward :)

Comment: When you're writing Angular apps, I recommend forgetting that jQuery exists.  Write everything using Angular's methods and plain ol' JavaScript.